# Get scenarios tags for current execution in NightwatchJS

Tags: cucumber, nightwatch.js, cucumberjs

Considering the scenario below

@featureTag
Feature: feature description

```
@scenarioTag @smoke
Scenario: Scenario description
    Given
    When
    Then
```

I need to retrieve the scenario tags for current execution on the code.
Is there any way to do it with NightwatchJS?

Comment: I don't remember seeing anything like that, but try console.log(browser) to get the entire browser object and look at the output to see if you can see.  I've found many solutions this way that were not noted in the Nightwatch docs.

Comment: also, after re-reading your question, I know you can use tags like `@tags: []` and put whatever you'd like into that array as a string.  I use these tags for smoke tests, bug regressions, etc.  As far as fetching that specific tag name I have not seen any way to retrieve it.